# how to change these lines of javascript from scriptaculous to jQuery syntax

Tags: php, jquery, scriptaculous

I am rewriting a helper class which was originally built on top of Scriptaculous. I am moving to jQuery - however, I am stuck on a couple of lines, that I need help with (see below): Note: the javascript code is interpersed with php variables (the sigils being a dead give away)

**Statement 1**

```
'new Insertion.Before(\'' . $updateContainer . '\', new Element(\'div\', {\'id\': \'' . $updateContainer . '_loading\', \'class\': \'' . $spinnerClass .'\'})); $(\'' . $updateContainer . '_loading\').innerHTML="<h4>Loading ...</h4>";',
```

**Statement 2**

```
'$(\'' . $updateContainer . '_loading\').remove();'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the `$updateContainer` is **ID** of the HTML element that contains the loading message.

Then, I'd write the Statement 1 like this:

```
$statement1 = sprintf('$(\'#%1$s\').html(\'<div id="%1$s_loading" class="%2$s"><h4>Loading</h4></div>\');', $updateContainer, $spinnerClass);
```

And the second statement is:

```
$statement2 = sprintf('$(\'#%s_loading\').remove();', $updateContainer);
```

If you have a lot of AJAX communication and need the 'Loading' often, it might be better to `hide()` it so you can just `show()` it later instead of creating the HTML again.

Statement1 would be uset to create the loading element, Statement2 with `hide()` instead of `remove()` to hide it and Statement3 with `show()` instead of `hide()` to show it again.

Comment: Thanks Marko, I'll be sure to try this and let you know how it goes. If it works, I'll accept your answer as the final one.